# How to link a library that was created from add_subdirectory in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, dependencies

I am trying to build a program using CMake that depends on a third party library. This third party library contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file so what I want to do is keep the source code of the third party library within my project directory, and build it using `add_subdirectory(path/to/lib)`, and then link my target against the static library that the third party library generated.

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_version(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_project)

add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/somelib")

# my-code:
# somelib CMakeLists.txt file has a project name: SOMELIB
# which lets me access the directory where the files are built
# on windows it builds to /Release, on mac and linux it just builds
# to the binary dir
set(SOMELIB_LIBS "${SOMELIB_BINARY_DIR}/Release")
add_executable(my_program my_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_program "${SOMELIB_LIBS}/SOMELIB.lib" "${SOMELIB_LIBS}/SOMELIBmain.lib")
```

I then make a build directory and from that directory I do:

```sh
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..
cmake --build .
```

The build command fails with a "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'extern/somelib/Release/SOMELIBmain.lib' ..."

My workaround for now has been to comment out the part that says "#my-code", build the somelib dependency first which generates the static libraries, and then uncomment out my-code and build again which then works correctly.

**How can I tell CMake to build the subdirectory first, and then link against the static libraries that it generated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: tell CMake that there is dependency between its targets.

```
target_link_libraries(my_program PRIVATE SOMELIB SOMELIBmain)
```

CMake will evaluate SOMELIBs locations for you and link `my_program` against `SOMELIB` and `SOMELIBmain`<sup>[1]</sup>. Works for both Debug and Release configurations and also for Linux.

You shouldn't have to worry where CMake places build files<sup>[2]</sup> and this is what so called "modern CMake" is trying to achieve. I will leave here just brief description but check link on the bottom of answer<sup>[3]</sup>.

Anyway, the key concept is that whenever you create library/executable (target), you list its usage+build requirements and dependencies to other targets. You declare dependencies using `target_link_libraries(<your_lib> KEYWORD <dependencies>)`. Such line will not only make `<you_lib>` link against listed dependencies, it will inherit their usage requirements (usually, public include directories) and order CMake to build dependent libraries before `<your_lib>`.

The beauty of it is that even if `SOMELIB` does not follow modern CMake ideas (does not declare build/usage requirements), you still should be able to do just with this single line.

<sup>[1]</sup> I assumed that CMake targets are named same as output library names, but it is not mandatory. For OP's case it turned out that static library targets are suffixed with `-static`, so he had to write `SOMELIB-static SOMELIBmain-static`

<sup>[2]</sup> Unfortunately, it is not so easy with shared libraries on Windows (DLLs)

<sup>[3]</sup> I'd start with this blog entry: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/

Comment: I tried replacing `target_link_libraries(my_program "${SOMELIB_LIBS}/SOMELIB.lib" "${SOMELIB_LIBS}/SOMELIBmain.lib")` with `target_link_libraries(my_program PRIVATE SOMELIB SOMELIBmain)` but it still gives me an error saying it cannot find 'SOMELIB.lib'. Do I need to set properties of SOMELIB to tell cmake where it was built?

Comment: UPDATE: I looked at the CMakeLists.txt file of the library I need to build and it appends a '-static' to the target name when building static library files, so doing: `target_link_libraries(my_program SOMELIB-static SOMELIBmain) works. Thank you

Comment: @ns_helloworld Great :) I will update my answer with this remark for future readers