How could I link to so file generated by cmake add_subdirectory?
I have seen a similar question but I cannot make sense by that accepted answer.
my project structure is like this
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
└── plugins
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── plugin.cpp
    └── plugin.h

The content of CMakeLists.txt is like this:
# top-level CMakeLists.txt
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.22)

PROJECT(example)

add_subdirectory(./plugins/)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ./plugins/)
target_link_libraries(main -lplugin)

CMakeLists.txt in folder of ./plugins/
add_library(plugin SHARED plugin.cpp)

And the code is like this:
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "plugin.h"


int call() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "call\n";
    func();
}

int main() {
    call();
    return 0;
}

// plugins/plugin.cpp
#include <iostream>

void func() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "plugin\n";
}

// plugins/plugin.h
void func();

When I compile this, I got the error that
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'plugins/libplugin.so', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

Would you please tell me how to make this work?

If you define a library target plugin you should link to the target instead: target_link_libraries(main plugin)

@Botje Would you please leave an answer, and explain a bit why plugin works but -lplugin does not work. BTW, I found there is no libplugin.so in the output of ldd main. Do you know why ?

[OT] target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ./plugins/) should probably be target_include_directories(plugin INTERFACE .) in plugins

@Jarod42 Link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210202/how-to-link-a-library-that-was-created-from-add-subdirectory-in-cmake

If you change your target_link_libraries call to the following:
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC plugin)

CMake will:

Add a dependency from the main target to the plugin target.
Configure main such that it knows where to find libplugin.so


Those two lines are basically wrong:
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ./plugins/)
target_link_libraries(main -lplugin)

it should be just:
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC plugin)

Which means: link target and its PUBLIC/INTERFACE properties (like include paths) into main target.
To make it work you have to correct plugins/CMakeLists.txt in this form:
add_library(plugin SHARED plugin.cpp)

target_include_directories(plugin PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

The last line means "use current source directory as include path in target plugin and in all targets which are linking plugin target.

Also I would recommend create a directory for a main target and name it better. Top level CMakeLists.txt should not provide any targets just add subdirectories with targets.
Live demo - compiles and runs fine.

You have to use target_link_libraries(main plugin):
As explain in the doc of target_link_libraries

target_link_libraries(<target> ... <item>... ...)
Each  may be:

A library target name: The generated link line will have the full path to the linkable library file associated with the target. The buildsystem will have a dependency to re-link  if the library file changes.
[..]
A link flag: Item names starting with - [..]
Link flags specified here are inserted into the link command


So library target adds a dependency to the target, whereas link flag don't.
